# Differentiate $\sin \sqrt{x^2+1} $with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

Differentiate $$ \sin \sqrt{x^2+1} $$ with respect to $x$?

Can someone please help me with question, im very lost.

Comment: Do you know about the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement)?

Comment: do you know the chain rule of differentiation?

Comment: Chain rule. $\sin \circ \operatorname{sqrt} \circ \operatorname{plus1} \circ \operatorname{square}$.

Comment: A real question: can our compulsive anwerers restrain themselves until Red returns and repsonds to the hints.

Comment: @GEdgar For a real question it's lacking on question marks.

Comment: Ive heard of it but not familiar with chain rule

Comment: I would suggest you [become familiar](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ChainRule.aspx) with the chain rule first; then return to this problem.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 You need to check your notes. Chain rule is the key here. I suggest you read your notes and come back with either an answer for your own question or questions about why you can't use it here.

Comment: Well read several notes on how to use chain rule here, im still unsure, can some just start me off?

Comment: There are four elementary functions nested here: you have to apply the chain rule repeadetly.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 This is a tough example for a first introduction to the chain rule. How did you run into this problem? There should be easier ones first.

Comment: long story short, I was flicking through books an seemingly found a cool question(this question) and tried to do it. Im sure I know how to do it, ive learnt it before just forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \dfrac {d}{dx}\sin \sqrt{x^2+1} $$
since $\dfrac {d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x,\dfrac {d}{dx} x^n=n\cdot x^{n-1},\dfrac{d}{dx}C=0$ C is Constant

so $$ \dfrac {d}{dx}\sin \sqrt{x^2+1}\implies\cos \sqrt{x^2+1}\dfrac {d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
like this continue the differentiation of functions (here differentiate $\sqrt{x^2+1}$).
Just try to solve it is very simple then.

Answer (score 3):

Ayush is incorrect, the chain rule is actually:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

Which would make your answer

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin\sqrt{x^2+1} = \cos\sqrt{x^2+1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1} = \cos\sqrt{x^2+1} \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$.

You can check the answer with wolfram alpha.

Comment: The differential quotient $\left(\frac{d}{d(g(x))}f(x)\right)$ is weird. I think you'd better change it into something like $f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: I was considering doing that but I didn't know what form Red Queen is familiar with and wanted to be more explicit. I agree that that is more correct though, and I'll edit as such.

Answer (score 1):

OK, since you're not that familiar with the chain rule, let me simplify that for you.

**Chain rule of differentiation:**
$$\frac{d}{dx}f\left(g\left(x \right) \right) =\left( \left.\frac{d}{dy}f(y)\right|_{y=f(x)} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{d}{dx}g(x) \right)$$

So,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin \sqrt{x^2+1} \right)=
\frac{d}{dy}\left.\left(\sin y \right)\right|_{y=\sqrt{x^2+1}}
\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left( \sqrt{x^2+1} \right) 
$$

**Your answer:** $$=\cos (\sqrt{x^2+1})\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2 + 1}}$$

Comment: @Ayush This is wrong. That's probably why you got a downvote.

Comment: @GitGud this is correct answer what is wrong in it

Comment: the answer was wrong before someone edited it. but now its correct. but I think theres something wrong with the format, its not showing up properly

Comment: don't worry now it is

Comment: @iostream007 You have almost 3K. Did the new user really have to tell you about it?

Comment: his second step was not accurate but answer was correct

Comment: @iostream007 He edited the answer.

Comment: It's ridiculous that this answer has 4 upvotes while others which were correct from the start have only one. I can't swear or insult anybody in here, but to the upvoters: please feel insulted.

Comment: funny after your comment the upvote droped by 2 @Git Gud

Comment: @GitGud Apparently, it was someone else who made the necessary corrections.

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh, right. I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: The edits are accepted, they're right. But that was the way I was taught in school (back in the eleventh grade I guess), to work in functions rather than substitute variables, probably to make things easier for us back then. So, thank you everyone for your suggestions/reviews.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Actually the upvotes didn't drop. What happened was that some people downvoted the answer. When you get enough rep. you can see how many upvotes and how many downvotes there are. As you are, you only see the the number $\text{upvotes}-\text{downvotes}$.

Comment: Oh yes, and I think I used $x$ instead of $\sqrt {x^2+1}$. I'm so sorry for that!