# Differentiating $\tan\left(\frac{1}{ x^2 +1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate: $\displaystyle \tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2 +1}\right)$

Do I use the quotient rule for this question? If so how do I start it of?

Comment: What about using the same method that was pointed out in your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450269/differentiate-sin-sqrtx21-with-respect-to-x) ?

Comment: For all $x\in \Bbb R$ define $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. What you want is $(\tan \circ f)'$, next just follow zuggg's advice.

Comment: And, perhaps you know the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\sec^2 x$.

Comment: so I still use chain rule?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay thanks. ill give it a try

Comment: @RedQueen10101 If no one does in the mean time, it would be good practice to post an answer yourself.

Comment: Do you mean post the answer to this question?

Comment: Note when using the chain rule, you'll have to differentiate $1\over x^2+1$; here, you could use the quotient rule. Or, you could write this expression as $(x^2+1)^{-1}$ and have more fun with the chain rule.

Comment: You will have three factors, owing to the three levels of composition exhibited by your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the chain rule to evaluate  $$ \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\tan \frac{1}{x^2 +1}\right)$$

Since we have a function which is a composition of functions: $\tan(f(x))$, where $f(x) = \dfrac 1{1+x^2}$, this screams out *chain-rule*!

Now, recall that $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\tan x) = \sec^2 x$$

and to evaluate $f'(x) = \dfrac d{dx}\left(\dfrac 1{1 + x^2}\right)$, we can use either the quotient rule, or the chain rule. Using the latter, we have $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac 1{1 + x^2}\right)= \dfrac{d}{dx}(1 + x^2)^{-1} = -(1 + x^2)^{-2}\cdot \dfrac d{dx}(1+ x^2) = -\dfrac{2x}{(1+ x^2)^2}$$

Now, we put the "chain" together: $$\dfrac d{dx}\left(\tan \left(\frac{1}{ x^2 +1}\right)\right) = \dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(\tan(f(x)\Big)\cdot \Big(f'(x)\Big) = \sec^2 \left(\dfrac 1{1 + x^2}\right)\cdot \left(-\dfrac{2x}{(1+ x^2)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Nicely illustrated chain-rule +1

Answer (score 5):

Let $$f(x)=\tan x$$ and $$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ so $$f'(x)=1+\tan^2 x$$ and $$g'(x)=\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$ and you want differentiate $f(g(x))$ so use the chaine rule:
$$(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\times g'$$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \frac d {dx}\tan\frac 1 {1+x^2}$

$\displaystyle=\left(\frac d {du} \tan u\right)\left(\frac d {dx}\frac 1 {1+x^2}\right)$ [Chain rule]

$=\cdots$ [Quotient rule]

Answer (score 0):

Answering this one too now, I'll write the steps straight away

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)=
\frac{d}{dy}\left.\left(\tan y \right)\right|_{y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}}
\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)$$

$$=\sec^2y|_{y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}} \cdot \left( - \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)$$

$$=\sec^2 \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right) \cdot \left( - \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not a quotient. It is the *tangent* of a quotient, in other words $f(x) = \tan g(x)$ or equivalently $f = \tan \circ \, g$. It is a composition of functions. If you have been given this exercise then you must have been taught how to differentiate a composition: $(u\circ v)' = (u' \circ\, v) \cdot v'$.