# Finding the derivative of $\sin \sqrt {x^2+1}$ from the definition?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

This means finding $\lim_{h \to 0} \large \large \frac{\sin \sqrt {(x+h)^2+1}-\sin \sqrt {x^2+1}}{h}$ . The only way I could think of to do this is to replace $h$ by some function $f(h)$ such that   $[x+f(h)]^2+1=[x+g(h)]^2$ and this would get rid of one of the square roots, but I was not able to find $f(h)$ .

Inspired by: [Differentiate $\sin \sqrt {x^2+1}$ with respect to x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450269/differentiate-sin-sqrtx21-with-respect-to-x)

Comment: You're a brave guy.

Comment: If you want to cheat somewhat, you could explicitly make use of the chain rule in formal limit procedures and multiply and divide by $\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1}$. If you don't want to do that, I'm at a loss and @GitGud's sentiments would be mine exactly.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Haha I would not want to do that

Comment: @GitGud Then I might just turn this into the question of finding that $f(h)$ because that seems to me an interesting question on its own

Comment: @Ovi In that case: You are a braver man than I.

Comment: Be sure to wear your hair shirt before working on it :)

Comment: @Ovi You might want to look at the proof for the chain rule; the textbook I have for analysis first provides a faulty proof that shows that the "intuitive" thing to do isn't necessarily correct. But by seeing the proof of the chain rule, it may hint at the necessary steps you may want to take.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Then in that case let's use the cheat

Comment: Heh. That's what lemmas are for. As @Alex suggested, it'd be  a heck of a lot easier to establish the chain rule, the power rule, and the derivative of $\sin x$ from first principles than do the "hair shirt" derivation.

Comment: It is fun to pretend it is painful, but it really is easy, no lemmas. The only nuisance is the typing.

Comment: @Alex: The wrong proof you refer to doesn't work for the general case, but it does work here, or any time when the inside functions injective. ($x^2$ isn't injective, but it is injective in a neighborhood of each point except $0$, and even at $0$ there is no problem. Injectiveness is stronger than what is needed, namely discrete fibers.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are interested in the behaviour of $\frac{\sin(f(x+h))-\sin(f(x))}{h}$ as $h\to 0$.

Note that by the sum (or rather difference) to product formula for $\sin A-\sin B$, the top is equal to 
$$\sin\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{f(x+h)+f(x)}{2}\right).$$

Tbe cos part will cause no trouble. For the sine part, rationalize the numerator as usual.

When we rationalize and divide by $h$, the sine part looks like
$$\frac{\sin(g(x,h))}{h}$$
where
$$g(x,h)=\frac{2xh+h^2}{2\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}+2\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

The same trick as the one we use to evaluate $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}$ now works, just a little messier to type.

**Remark:** The above is very much worth not doing.

Comment: I love the wording "worth not doing" instead of "not worth doing."